# Nativescript Vertical Screen Slide / ViewPager

Tags: android, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

What is the easiest way to implement a screen slide in Nativescript like shown in [Android Viewpager](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html) , but in a **vertical direction** ? Another example of this functionality would be the rss reader `feedly` where you can change rss feeds by swiping up/down.

The page should allow vertical scrolling to the top/bottom and then transition after a certain treshold.

I already encountered [nativescript-slides](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-slides), which can only do horizontally sliding.

So is there a "nativescript" way or do i have to implement it as native android/ios feature (for example [by this](https://github.com/castorflex/VerticalViewPager)) ? In either case a sample on how to integrate it in nativescript would be great.

**Update**

Recorded an example:

[image]

taken from [this Repo](https://github.com/castorflex/VerticalViewPager) with Android native code. The outstanding [PR](https://github.com/castorflex/VerticalViewPager/pull/14) made changes to offer vertical scrolling in the list. But the repo seems to be outdated and a bit buggy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can provide more info later but there's a new plugin implementing the native controls for android and iOS for slides/carousel her https://github.com/alexrainman/nativescript-carousel-view and vertical swiping is on his radar, I think he might even be close to completing that.

Comment: Looks like one problem to get past and then vertical will be shipped https://github.com/alexrainman/nativescript-carousel-view/issues/3

Comment: that would be great!

Comment: Think it's ready to go https://github.com/alexrainman/nativescript-carousel-view `orientation` looks to be what you want (vertical/horizontal it seems) have not tried myself.

Comment: looks very promising. However, it does not support vertical scrolling inside a ListView (or other content that exceeds screen size) before sliding to the next page. But i think that is outside the plugin scope. I have to figure out a way for the ListView to intercept the touch event and if the listView is at the starting or end point, it should propagate to the vertical screen slide. Otherwise only the list should be scrollable .

Comment: Yea I'd consider that an advanced layout :) but I'm going from your description. It might be simpler if i could see what you're after.

Comment: updated my question with a gif example. hope , that helps :-)

Comment: Yea. Never tried anything like that. So does the carousel-view plugin not handle listviews inside the current layout? Any errors or just doesn't work?

Comment: in the area of the ListView the screen slide is hidden by the vertical scroll event of the list. hmm i think i have to spend some time on android development to understand the issue and then transfer it to nativescript. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

To give an answer for anybody interested in above nested scrolling animation:

For Android I had to implement the native `ReyclerView` in Nativescript in favor of the NS buildin `ListView`. It is an optimized view structure which among other things allows nested (vertical) scrolling and can be used as replacement for an ordinary list.

Together with https://github.com/alexrainman/nativescript-carousel-view works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Anyone that ends up here still looking for ways to achieve this.

I spent a lot of time trying to figure out a way to achieve this and tried to find ready plugins for this. Also tried to use the plugin from Alexrainman but eventually gave up since the plugin was not up to date with the current nativescript-version.

My solution:
I used radListView as a basis for this implementation and leveraged the methods and events on the radListView.

By using scrolled-event I gathered data for the use of the scrolling feature: scroll Speed and scroll direction. (These might be also taken from the event data, but since I did not find the event details from the Nativescript-documentation I gave up trying to guess where to find this data on the event-model).

Then I also saved the fixed height of one item on my list (The height I fixed to screenHeight-200).

With all this info, I managed to hook the event "ScrollDragEnded" and add logic that makes my list behave like a vertical slider. Moving on the list by method "scrollToIndex" and figuring out which index to scroll and when by leveraging all the data mentioned above.

This is the way I managed to make a pretty good vertical slide.

Good luck!